# What does Helsinki say to Oslo in Russian in Money Heist, at the end of S01E12?

Tags: dialogue, translation, money-heist

I couldn't understand since it's Russian. What does Helsinki say to Oslo at the end of the 12th episode of the first season of the *La casa de papel* (international title *Money heist*), while the second is on the ground?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Upon Helsinki seeing Oslo laying on the ground, injured, he says the following in **Serbian**:

> HELSINKI: Hey, bro! My brother. What have they done to you, bro? What have they done to you, those dirty motherfuckers? I'm gonna fuck them up, bro! I'm gonna kill them all!

---

Edit: It appears that Netflix has since updated their captions for this scene and the spoken language was in fact Serbian.

Comment: that is not russian

Comment: Note that Oslo and Helsinki are Serbians, not Russians.

Comment: Okay, some clarification -- the translation provided in this answer was taken directly from Netflix's subtitles and was denoted as being Russian. I suppose I can research this a little more since Money Heist is an even more popular show as of late.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 8):

It has nothing to do with Russian, it’s Serbian.
I’m a Serbian myself so I’ll translate it to you from the first hand.
Before he kills him with the pillow, he says: "Kume promise me one thing: you’re not gonna be mad at me."
Kume means godfather, but usually that’s just the way we great our good friends or relatives.
I’m so sorry that they didn’t translate all of their talk because they had so many funny conversations.

Comment: This is good but I believe the pillow scene was an episode or two later than the one the OP asked about (i.e., S01E12).

Answer (score 4):

I'm Serbian myself and I really tried to translate these phrases well, but English speakers don't have any phrases similar to what Helsinki was saying. As per my understanding

1. They're and speaking Serbian.
2. He keeps repeating

> What have they done to you brother

and

> I'll fuck their mothers

I hope I helped you out here.